# How to Use Oracle Database in Entity Data Model

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am able to add Oracle database in Data Source -> Server Explorer,
[image]

The problem is, when I use **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** extension, I dont see Oracle Database option.

[image]

[image]

Do I need to install anything else to get Oracle Database option?
I ma using VS2022 Professional.
Application is using 4.5.2 framework.